# Python adding an integer to a list

Tags: python

I am trying to add 1 to my variable and then add this variable to a list so when I print out my list, the value of the variable is within it. However, my code prints out an empty list despite me adding the variable to it.

```
case_number = 0
case_numbers = []

issue = input('Has the issue been solved?').lower()
if issue == 'no':
      case_number += 1
      case_numbers+[int(case_number)]
      print(case_numbers)
```

Comment: `+` creates a new list which you're discarding. What you want is `case_numbers.append(int(case_number))`

Comment: You need to replace the final before last line with `case_numbers+=[int(case_number)]`

Comment: You have a misprint, write `case_numbers+=[int(case_number)]` (forgot the equal)

Comment: or use `case_numbers.append(...)`.

Comment: `case_numbers.append(int(case_number))` is the standard way. The reason your approach doesn't change the list is that you don't assign the modified list back to `case_numbers` e.g. `case_numbers = case_numbers + [int(case_number)]`

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, adding the equals to the final before last line worked :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a value to a growing list you need to use `list.append()`  method. It adds the value to the end of the list, so you code should be:

```
case_number = 0
case_numbers = []

issue = input('Has the issue been solved?').lower()
if issue == 'no':
      case_number += 1
      case_numbers.append(int(case_number))
      print(case_numbers)
```

Extra tip:
`list.append()` method adds value to end of list so if you add the list B into list A using `append()` then it will add the listB inside the listA like this `listA.append(listB)= ["a","b","c",["d","e","f"]]` so if you want to add the values as normal list you should use `list.extend()` method which will add the values of one list to another such that `listA.extend(listB)=["a","b","c","d","e","f"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
if issue == 'no':
      case_number += 1
      case_numbers.append(case_number)
      print(case_numbers)
```

Here, `case_numbers.append(case_number)` statements add the elements to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
case_numbers+[int(case_number)]
```

While it's true that you can append values to a list by adding another list onto the end of it, you then need to assign the result to a variable.  The existing list is not modified in-place.  Like this:

```
case_numbers = case_numbers+[int(case_number)]
```

However, this is far from the best way to go about it.  For a start, you don't need to convert your case_number value to an int, because it already is an int.  Also, lists have an append method for this exact purpose.

```
case_numbers.append(case_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `append` or `insert` :

`insert`is used like the following :

```
case_numbers.insert(0,case_number) #will insert it at first
```

or `append` like this :

`case_numbers.append(case_number)`

check this link : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/python-list/?utm_source=feedly